How to Include External Files in PlantUML for Gantt Diagram Custom Functions?
I am working on a Gantt diagram using PlantUML. Due to the nature of Gantt charts, I needed a way to convert arbitrary dates into epoch_time. Since PlantUML doesn’t seem to provide a built-in function for this, I created a custom function to handle the conversion.
Here is the function I implemented:
https://gist.github.com/topchul/e635a3003ab1387d2fc9d92a09dc0249
I included the function directly inside an @startgantt block and verified that it works as expected. However, when I try to reference this function from multiple .pu files using !include, I encounter issues.
Here’s the problem:

When using !include with a local file, it throws an error.
When using !include with the raw Gist URL, the diagram generation halts, and the !dump_memory command doesn’t execute.

Here is a sample script demonstrating the issue:
@startuml test
' !include to_epoch_time.pu

[%filename() - 2 ]
[%file_exists("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/topchul/e635a3003ab1387d2fc9d92a09dc0249/raw/9a0cb98438d43c8099e0c1f2266b864eadbe2a17/to_epoch_time.pu") - exists 1]
[%file_exists("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/topchul/e635a3003ab1387d2fc9d92a09dc0249/raw/9a0cb98438d43c8099e0c1f2266b864eadbe2a17/to_epoch_time_1.pu") - exists 2]

' !include https://gist.githubusercontent.com/topchul/e635a3003ab1387d2fc9d92a09dc0249/raw/9a0cb98438d43c8099e0c1f2266b864eadbe2a17/to_epoch_time.pu
' !include https://gist.githubusercontent.com/topchul/e635a3003ab1387d2fc9d92a09dc0249/raw/9a0cb98438d43c8099e0c1f2266b864eadbe2a17/to_epoch_time_1.pu
!dump_memory
[$to_epoch_time("2024-01-01")]
@enduml

Questions:

Can you provide an example of how to properly use !include for external files in PlantUML?
Is there any workaround or best practice to include a custom function like mine across multiple .pu files?
If possible, could you help resolve the specific issue I am facing?

Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I found the issue causing the empty error. While moving the file to Gist, the !return and !endfunction statements were missing, leading to the error. After fixing those, the function now works as expected with the Gist URL.
However, the problem with handling local files (!include local_file) still persists. I’ll investigate further and work on creating an updated guide for handling !include in PlantUML with gist, which I’ll share as a Gist once ready.
Thanks for your help and insights!

After reviewing my original code, I realized the root cause of the issue was a missing !return statement and the critical !endfunction declaration. These were omitted right before the @enduml tag in my initial implementation. Unfortunately, PlantUML doesn't provide a helpful error message in this case, which made debugging a bit challenging. It was a good reminder of how tricky it can be to review one's own code objectively.
That said, I’ve resolved the issue! Along the way, I also identified and fixed a related bug: when using %date("YYYY-MM-dd", %now()), failing to use the correct format string ("yyyy-MM-dd") could lead to errors after "2024-12-28". This issue has been addressed in my updated code.
For anyone struggling with converting dates to epoch_time, the logic isn’t overly complex, but feel free to refer to my solution below.
Resources:

Stable Gist Code: Gantt Utilities for PlantUML
Example of !include Usage: GRPlantUMLUtilities Test Cases
Original Code with Missing !endfunction: Problematic Gist

Hopefully, this helps others avoid similar pitfalls!
